# initialize dropdown values based on radio button cha

Tags: html, angularjs

```js
$scope.identityProof = ["karnataka","Tamilnadu","Andhra","Delhi","Kerala","Bihar"]
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="Yes" /> Yes <br />
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="No" /> No <br />
</form>


<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    {{message}} <br />

    <!--Options value is defualt 0, 1 ... and it's non change able -->
    <span>Default Otions:</span>
   <select id="idType" name="idProff" ng-model="completiondetail.IDProofType" ng-options="item.proofName as item.proofName for item in identityProof">
                      <option value="">--Choose a Document--</option>
                </select>


  </div>
</div>
```

I have two radio bottons "Yes" and "No". Dropdown values are coming from service response. So I'm displaying the values as it is.

1) When the page will load, that time dropdown will show "--Cjoose a Document -- " for first time.

2) If I will select the dropdown value as "Yes", I don't want to do anything and it should work asusual.

3) Incased if I will select the dropdown value as "No", I want to set "Delhi" in Dropdown. It should visible in a dropsown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your radio button should also be inside `<div ng-controller="...">` tag for angular to recognize the change in value. Then you can use `ng-change` to achieve what you want.

```
 <select ng-model="selectedVal" ng-options="b for b in identityProof track by b"></select>
<input type="radio" name="radio_select" value="yes" ng-model="selectedRadio"/>Yes
<input type="radio" name="radio_select" value="no" ng-model="selectedRadio" ng-change="selectedVal='Delhi'" />No
```

Here is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gilango/r1b0foaj/). Hope this helps!

Comment: In dropdown, by default the value is "TamilNadu". If I change yes it should change as "Delhi". Again If I select No , it should show the existing value same as "Tamilnadu". Can you please tell this. Its not updating again.

Comment: You have to set the `ng-model` of dropdown to Tamilnadu and add `ng-change` which will set dropdown to Tamilnadu when user selects Yes. i would recommend you to read more on `ng-change` and try some examples. This link might give you a head start https://www.learnkode.com/Examples/Angular/Ng-Change

Answer (score 0):

It's an easy `ng-change` logic what you are looking for:

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="radio" 
         name="myRadio" 
         ng-model="radioValue" 
         ng-value="true" 
         ng-change="validateRadio()" /> Yes<br />
  <input type="radio" 
         name="myRadio" 
         ng-model="radioValue" 
         ng-value="false" 
         ng-change="validateRadio()" /> No<br />
  <br />
  <select id="idType" 
          name="idProff" 
          ng-model="completiondetail.IDProofType" 
          ng-options="item.proofName as item for item in identityProof track by item">
    <option value="" selected>--Choose a Document--</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.radioValue = false;
  $scope.identityProof = ["karnataka", "Tamilnadu", "Andhra", "Delhi", "Kerala", "Bihar"];
  $scope.completiondetail = {
    IDProofType: null
  };

  $scope.validateRadio = function() {
    if ($scope.radioValue) {
      $scope.completiondetail.IDProofType = 'Delhi';
    }
  }
});
```

**> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvbL1k3z/)**